# Class instantiation process

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

What is the difference between the date in Class A and the date in Class B;

```
Class A {
  date: Date = new Date()
}
```

---

```
Class B {
  date: Date
  constructor() {
    this.date = new Date()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no big difference. In your case, both lead to the same JS output.

The second is better if you have a ton of props you. want to declare and give them types before giving (all or some) of the values in the constructor.

Also, you can you the first approach in creating a parent class and the second approach if you want some special code executed when you create the child classes.

I wound use the second approach, its clearer.